# How to print AWB in Fedex in an ASP.NET Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, fedex

I have integrated FedEx web service in my ASP.NET website for creating a Pickup. It only returns the confirmation number. I have to print the AWB. How to do this?

I have gone through the FedEx website for API service but we could not found any suitable API web service which can help me to implement create and print AWB functionality in our application.

Answer (score 0):

The Pickup Service does not generate a shipping label/AWB.  The Pickup Service is only used for dispatching a driver to pickup a package.  The Pickup Service assumes that the package already has a label/AWB.

You would need to use the Ship Service for generating a shipping label/AWB.